# How to add Multiple objects using indexes in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a menu-based system where it will calculate my monthly rent using specific variables (double - monthlyRent, double waterBill, double energyBill etc.)

The program starts with prompting the user to select an option:

(1)  create a budget invoice (this is where a projected monthly rent invoice will be calculated)

When the user selects this option I want to use an ArrayList to store the monthly rent invoices. I have a variable where the user can put an InvoiceID to search an already existing monthly rent invoices or delete etc.

My problem is how to use specific indexes in my ArrayList to input monthly rent, water bill and so forth and the next index will be a different monthly rent, waterbill, energy bill etc.). In a general sense, store multiple variable and variable types within 1 index of the ArrayList.

My ArrayList is in its own class, different from the function that I want to create to generate monthly budget invoices. My problem is how to prompt user input for each rent variable and store all of those inputs in its proper index of the ArrayList where that specific monthly invoice will be stored. The variables are double, string and int types.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InvoicerHub {

    
    static ArrayList<Object> invoicerSys = new ArrayList<Object>();
    
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BudgetInvoice extends InvoicerHub {

    protected double monthlyRent ;
    
    protected double waterBill;
    
    protected double energyBill;
    
    protected double carRent; 
    
    protected double internetRent;
    
    protected String invoiceID;

     public int counter = 0; 
     
     
    static Scanner myScan= new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    
    public double getMonthlyRent() {
        return monthlyRent;
    }

    public void setMonthlyRent(double monthlyRent) {
        this.monthlyRent = monthlyRent;
    }

    public double getWaterBill() {
        return waterBill;
    }

    public void setWaterBill(double waterBill) {
        this.waterBill = waterBill;
    }

    public double getEnergyBill() {
        return energyBill;
    }

    public void setEnergyBill(double energyBill) {
        this.energyBill = energyBill;
    }

    public double getCarRent() {
        return carRent;
    }

    public void setCarRent(double carRent) {
        this.carRent = carRent;
    }

    public double getInternetRent() {
        return internetRent;
    }

    public void setInternetRent(double internetRent) {
        this.internetRent = internetRent;
    }

    public String getInvoiceID() {
        return invoiceID;
    }

    public void setInvoiceID(String invoiceID) {
        this.invoiceID = invoiceID;
    }
    
    
    
    public static InvoicerHub getInvoice() 
    
    {
        
        
        invoicerSys = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (invoicerSys.isEmpty()== true) 
        {
            
        } // This is where I'm stuck.
```

Comment: Why does `BudgetInvoice` extend `InvoicerHub`? I doubt an invoice is a specific type of `InvoicerHub`. Secondly, in your `getInvoice` method, you initialize `invoicerSys` to a new, empty `ArrayList` and then test to see if it is empty - of course it is.

Comment: So what should I do ? im fairly new to programming so this is why im asking for help

Comment: I would: Remove the parent class from `BudgetInvoice`. Remove method `getInvoice` from `BudgetInvoice`. Make `invoicerSys` non-static and make it an `ArrayList<BudgetInvoice>` explicitly. You could then create a static method in `BudgetInvoice` that returns a new `BudgetInvoice` object and that contains all of the logic needed to get the details from the user. I would then call this method from within `InvoicerHub` which can manage adding it to the `ArrayList<BudgetInvoice>`.